# Jackson issue with BasicSerializerFactory and NullSerializer with modifiers "private"

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Help!  I am looking for ideas

I am getting this error while using Jackson to serialize my Java object.

```
Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory 
can not access a member of class 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer 
with modifiers "private"
```

In other responses, this problem seems to have something to do with mixing versions of Jackson

[Spring : FasterXML cannot access a member of class with modifiers private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457895/spring-fasterxml-cannot-access-a-member-of-class-with-modifiers-private)

However, I can not find any collisions.

My pom.xml has these dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Dependency for AWS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Dependency for Restlet 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.fileupload</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for Apache Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for XBean Spring (for ActiveMQ use) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for Xuggler 5.4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--Needed by xuggler to work-->
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for JSpeex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jspeex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jspeex</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for Wowza -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.farng.mp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jid3lib</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-amazonutil</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-ant</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-commons-modeler</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-drm</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-dvr</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-httpstreamer-cupertinostreaming</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-httpstreamer-sanjosestreaming</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-httpstreamer-smoothstreaming</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-jlayer</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-mediareader-flv</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-mediareader-h264</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-mediareader-mp3</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-mediareader-smil</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-mediawriter-flv</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-mediawriter-h264</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-server</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-stream-file</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-stream-live</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-stream-publish</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-stream-record</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-stream-rtp</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-stream-shoutcast</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wowzamedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>wms-transcoder</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And mvn tree:dependencies gives me

```
 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ recognizer-wowza ---
 com.babelcentral:recognizer-wowza:jar:dev-SNAPSHOT
 +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.2:compile
 +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.2:compile
 +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.2:compile
 |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.2:compile - version managed from 2.7.0; omitted for duplicate)
 |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.7:compile
 +- com.babelcentral:recognizer-speech:jar:dev-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
 |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
 |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile - version managed from 2.3; omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.3)
 |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
 |  |     \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile - version managed from 2.3; omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:compile - version managed from 1.6.4; omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:compile
 |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  \- (xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 +- org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.7:compile
 +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.5:compile
 +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.4.1:compile
 |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
 |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
 |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
 |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
 |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
 |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
 |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
 |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:asm-all-repackaged:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
 |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:cglib:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
 |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
 +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.5.1:compile
 |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:compile - version managed from 1.5.11; omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
 |  |  +- (org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
 |  +- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.5.1:compile
 |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:compile - version managed from 1.5.11; omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:compile
 |  +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.1.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile - version managed from 3.0.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:compile
 |  \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.7:compile
 +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-events:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  +- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codedeploy:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codepipeline:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-config:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecs:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecr:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-workspaces:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-machinelearning:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directory:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-efs:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codecommit:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-devicefarm:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-waf:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-inspector:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iot:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-gamelift:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |  |  \- (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.59:compile
 |     +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
 |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile
 |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.3:compile
 |     |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
 |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
 |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.2:compile - version managed from 2.5.3; omitted for duplicate)
 |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
 +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
 +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.xml:jar:2.2.2:compile
 |  \- (org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.2.2:compile
 |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.org.json:jar:2.0:compile
 |  \- (org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.fileupload:jar:2.2.2:compile
 |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
 |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 2.2; omitted for duplicate)
 |  \- (org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
 +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.7:compile
 |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
 |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.3)
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
 |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.3)
 |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
 |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.3)
 +- xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.4:provided (scope not updated to compile)
 |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:provided - version managed from 1.6.4; omitted for duplicate)
 |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.1:provided
 |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.0:provided
 |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.0:provided
 |     +- (ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.0:provided - omitted for duplicate)
 |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:provided - version managed from 1.6.4; omitted for duplicate)
 +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:compile
 +- jspeex:jspeex:jar:0.9.7:compile
 +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:provided (scope not updated to compile)
 +- bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15:jar:146:provided
 +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided (scope not updated to compile)
 +- org.farng.mp3:jid3lib:jar:0.5.4:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-amazonutil:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-ant:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-bootstrap:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-commons-modeler:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-core:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-drm:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-dvr:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-httpstreamer-cupertinostreaming:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-httpstreamer-sanjosestreaming:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-httpstreamer-smoothstreaming:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-jlayer:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-mediareader-flv:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-mediareader-h264:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-mediareader-mp3:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-mediareader-smil:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-mediawriter-flv:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-mediawriter-h264:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-server:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-stream-file:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-stream-live:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-stream-publish:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-stream-record:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-stream-rtp:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-stream-shoutcast:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- com.wowzamedia:wms-transcoder:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
 +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:test
 |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:test - omitted for conflict with 1.0.3)
 |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
 \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.2:test
    \- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough: you need to show code you are trying to use for serialization as well as value(s) you are trying to serialize.

The problem appears to be due to something trying to serialize one of Jackson's internal classes; `NullSerializer` should never be serialized. Perhaps something is being called with wrong arguments (or in wrong order).

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  One of my classes to be serialized had @JsonProperty on set methods like this

```
@JsonProperty
public void setFoo( int foo ) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
```

I don't know why Jackson failed as it did, but removing the @JsonProperty(s) cured the problem.

I'd call that a *really* obscure message >:-(